# Design for four relationship tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, relationship

I am seeking for input in creating a design for the following tables. A door can be related to an edge, design, and/or inside. Should I create a relationship tables for each pair?

i.e. 
door-edge-table
door-design-table
door-inside-table

Any suggestions?

**Door**

```
door_id | name
--------+-----
1       | Bryce
2       | Renea
```

**Edge**

```
edge_id | name
--------+-----
1       | Straight
2       | Curved
```

**Design**

```
design_id | name
--------+-----
1       | Arch
2       | Solid
```

**Inside**

```
inside_id | name
--------+-----
1       | Regular
2       | Square
```

Comment: It depends on your purpose.

Comment: It's for cataloging doors with their respective attributes.

Comment: Yes, but what is a "door"? For instance, does each row in the Door table represent one "door"? for instance, can that row have a column called "Edge_id", because Door="Bryce" means there is only one possible Edge id? Or is your "Door" table actually "door brand"? You need to work out the semantics and for each combination above, ask whether there's a one-to-one, or one-to-many, or many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a 'doors' table with fields id, name, edge, design and inside, where the final three fields are foreign keys to those tables. I assume that a door can only have one kind of edge, one kind of design and one kind of inside.

If a door has more than one kind of edge (or design, or inside) then you will need a link table with two rows, door and edge.